# Showing a property of the zariski topology

Tags: commutative-algebra, zariski-topology

I have the following problem:

> Let $R$ be a ring and $a\subset R$.
>   $V_R(a):=\{p\in Spec \ R \ | \ a\subset p\}\subset Spec \ R$
>
> Show: Let $(a_i)_{i\in I}$ be a family of subsets of $R$ then the following is true
>   $$ \bigcap_{i\in I}V_R(a_i)=V_R(\bigcup_{i\in I}a_i)$$

I see why this equation has to be true, but in our script it is not proven, because it should be obvious. My problem is that I don't know how to proof it. Is it really that simple to show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working with the Zariski topology can be tricky at first. In this case, the result follows directly from the definitions:
$$
\begin{align*}
\bigcap_{i \in I} V_R(a_i) &= \bigcap_{i \in I}\{p \in \text{Spec}R; a_i \subseteq p\}\\ &= \{p \in \text{Spec}R; a_i \subseteq p \ \forall i \in I\}\\ &= \{p\in \text{Spec} R; \cup_{i\in I}a_i \subseteq p\} = V_R\left(\bigcup_{i \in I}a_i\right).
\end{align*}
$$

It follows from this that sets of the form $V_R(a)$ are closed under arbitrary intersection. Together with the facts that these sets are closed under finite union (exercise), $V_R(\emptyset) = \text{Spec}R$ and $V_R(R) = \emptyset,$ this shows that sets of the form $V(a)$ may be considered as the closed sets in a topology on $\text{Spec}A.$ This topology is called the Zariski topology.

A friend recently shared this with me, and I found it to be a good heuristic motivation for the definition of the Zariski topology: https://blogs.ams.org/mathgradblog/2017/07/16/idea-scheme/.